# JUnit test using H2 database passes in debug mode but fails in test mode

Tags: java, junit, h2

The error that I am getting is

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

at the 5th line. Because response only has an empty array. The array gets populated in the debug mode perfectly. Debugging is not easy. Not sure if it matters. Thanks for your time.

Please find the Java test and properties files below.

````java
        @Test
            public void testApplication() throws Exception {

                String ResourceUrl = "/mdh/v";

                String values = "205,2019-12-31";

                ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity(ResourceUrl, String.class);
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<Map<String, String>> list = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), List.class);

                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = list.get(0).entrySet().iterator();

                String expected_values[] = values.split(",", -1);
                int i = 0;
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();

                    if (expected_values[i].isEmpty())
                        assertEquals(String.valueOf("null"), String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));

                    else if (isValidInteger(expected_values[i].trim(), 10)) {
                        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(expected_values[i]), Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(entry.getValue())));
                    } else if (isValidDouble(expected_values[i].trim())) {
                        assertEquals(Double.valueOf(expected_values[i]), Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(entry.getValue())));
                    } else if (isValidDate(expected_values[i].trim())
                            && (expected_values[i].contentEquals(String.valueOf(entry.getValue())) == false)) {

                        Long ts = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        String dt = formatter.format(ts);
                        assertEquals(expected_values[i], dt);

                    } else {
                        assertEquals(expected_values[i], String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.OK));
                HttpHeaders httpHeaders = testRestTemplate.headForHeaders(ResourceUrl);
                assertTrue(httpHeaders.getContentType().includes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            }
    ```    

application-test.properties:


       spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MYSQL;
        spring.datasource.username=sa
        spring.datasource.password=password
        spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
        spring.datasource.platform=h2
        m.t.tableName=MOCK_TF_m_t_RESULT 
        spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=600000
        spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=80
        spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=80
        spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=60000
        spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=6000
        spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
        spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=6000000


        #m.t.marketData.where[1] = WHERE upper(${m.t.aClass.column}) = upper('%1$s') AND upper(${m.t.service.column}) = upper('%2$s') AND ${m.t.vDate.column} = DATE '%3$s' 
        #m.t.marketData.where[2] = WHERE upper(${m.t.aClass.column}) = upper('%1$s') AND upper(${m.t.service.column}) = upper('%2$s') AND ${m.t.vDate.column} = DATE '%3$s' AND upper(${m.t.vDate.subArea.column}) = upper('%4$s') AND upper(${m.t.vDate.serviceFrequency.column}) = upper('%5$s') 
        #m.t.marketData.sql[0]= SELECT  ${m-t-result.columnList.cdities} FROM  ${m.t.tableName} WHERE upper(${m.t.aClass.column}) = upper('%1$s') AND upper(${m.t.service.column}) = upper('%2$s') AND ${m.t.vDate.column} = '%3$s'; 
        #m.t.marketData.sql[0]= SELECT  ${m-t-result.columnList.cdities} FROM  MOCK_TF_m_t_RESULT WHERE upper(${m.t.aClass.column}) = upper('%1$s') AND upper(${m.t.service.column}) = upper('%2$s') AND ${m.t.vDate.column} = PARSEDATETIME('%3$s','dd-MMMM-yy'); 
        m.t.marketData.vDate.Condn =  ${m.t.vDate.column} = PARSEDATETIME('%3$s','dd-MMMM-yy')
        m-t-result.columnList.interestRates=ClientID,vDate,aClass,ServiceName,ServiceFrequency,SubArea

        #spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
        #disable spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto if you use schema.sql.
        #spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    ```
````

Comment: How is test setup different from debug setup?  What does your `application-debug.properties` file look like, by comparison?

Comment: can you print out the value of `response.getBody()` in `List<Map<String, String>> list = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), List.class);` ?

Comment: and is `objectMapper` the ObjectMapper from the jackson library?

Comment: @philip wrage there is no debug properties file

Comment: @Daniele.. response.getbody is [] ..

Comment: @Daniele com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

Comment: I added Thread.sleep at different places . It didnt help.

Comment: @Daniele response -  <200,[],[Content-Type:"application/json", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Date:"Wed, 18 Mar 2020 16:44:54 GMT"]>

Comment: Your edit to have both the code *and* the properties file in the same code block is **not** making this easier to read. Secondly: What is "at the 5th line"?

Comment: Also.. please add any clarification to your Question using [edit], so people don't have to find them in comments.

Comment: Thanks Scratte. THis is the fifth line -     Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = list.get(0).entrySet().iterator();Since response returned no data ,this line throws error